# How to validate Date selection "To" Date, maximum must be at least a year based on "From" Date selection

Tags: javascript

Okay so far I have set validation the minimum date must be after the selected date. However I need to set the maximum To Date at least a year after the "From" date. Is there also a way to reset the "From" date if the user enters in a date which is smaller then the "From" Date based on the "To" date values?

```
document.getElementById("firstDateId").onchange = function () {
var input = document.getElementById("secondDateId");

input.setAttribute("min", this.value);

document.getElementById("secondDateId").value = document.getElementById("firstDateId");
};
document.getElementById("firstId").onchange();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

```
if( moment(To).add(1, 'y');.isAfter(moment(From)) === true){
 //To + 1 year is after from
}else{
 //reset 
}}
```